# Git rebase in Intellij - how to select ALL temp commits as "squash" in one click?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, rebase

Using Intellij I like to do a rebase for a bunch of about 30 temp commits.

When I get to the rebase window, I'm asked what to do with each and every commit (pick, skip, edit, squash...).

Is there a way to tell Intellij "take ALL the commits and apply X on all of them" instead of manually click each and every on of the commits?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could select several commits with a mouse, or using `shift`, or `Ctrl+A` to select all, and then right click with a mouse, or use shortcuts to select the action for all selected commits

UPD. Starting from version 2020.2 it is possible to squash commits directly from the Log view, using the Squash Commits... action instead of Interactive Rebase.

Comment: I was able to select all relevant commits with `Shift` on the first and last commit, and then change one dropbox effects all selected commits. 10x!